# How to increase the frequency of light

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, frequency, photoelectric-effect

If we want to increase the energy of the emitted photoelectrons (in P.E) then we should increase the energy of the photons which are related to the frequency of the light, so how  is the frequency of light increased?

Answer (score 2):

Frequency of the emitted light depends on the nature of the source.

Eg:

- Incandescent -- depends on the temperature of the material
- Discharge Tubes -- depends on the characteristic spectrum of the gas

Comment: Can you give some source of reference for the temperature dependence of incandescent bulb? I would like to know the mathematical relation between frequency and temperature.

Comment: http://cistwiki.ufv.ca/pub/Phys382/ResearchLines/OPS004-Colour_Temp.pdf

Answer (score 1):

There is a general way to increase the frequency of light. It is [Doppler Effect](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/relativ/reldop2.html).
You can keep the observer (target for photoelectrons) and move the source of light towards it. 
But it is not practical, because you will need very high relative velocity to have any considerable change in  the frequency.

Answer (score 0):

we know that frequency is inversely proportional to the wavelength of light by the formula $f=\frac 1\lambda$'
So frequency will increase if wavelength is decreased.

Comment: This is a somewhat trivial answer, which does not explain too much. I guess, this was not the level of detail, the asking person will need to understand.

Comment: I thought OP was asking for this. Ok, I shall describe later.

Answer (score 0):

I am also pretty much unclear about it.

But thing of fire, fire at the bottom or where the fire starts, **the acceleration of charged particles is more, which means the frequency is also more and wavelength is short.** 
**As,** $$E=hv $$
Where E is total energy, h is Planck's constant and v is frequency.

The acceleration of charged particles is more as the temperature is more. **So, it results that providing some kind of energy to the light may increase the frequency.**

Wien's displacement law also states the relationship between temperature and wavelength. 
$$\lambda_\text{max}  = \frac{b}{T}$$